# For Android, taking an api key for showing maps

Tags: android, google-maps, cmd, android-keystore, not-exists

ı would like to show a map in my android project but i couldnt find SHA1 key... because i had taken an error which is below when i had been in CMD code.....
Thank you for your help

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. Tüm hakları saklıdır.

C:\Users\KürşadPC>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Kürşa
dPC\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass
android
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ?C:\Users\Kürş
adPC\.android\debug.keystore?
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: ?C:\Users\KürşadPC\.android\d
ebug.keystore?
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:742)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:340)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:333)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin>
```

Why debug.keystore didnt exist? when i looked at this directory i could find it (debug.keystore)

Comment: if you are using eclipse ADT then you can copy SHA1 key from Window>Preferences>Android>Build>SHA1 fingerprint

Comment: thank you for your help, i have already solved this problem